# matlab image processing- line passing through 2 points extending beyond the x1,y1 coordinate

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I have a problem to solve in matlab. I have 2 points A[x1,x2] and B[y1,y2] of my particles in Image. i want to plot a line between the 2 points and extend it beyond the x1,y1 coordinate alone.

i later check where it intersects.This will tell me where the particle originates. 
is there some simple code for this?

thank you

regards

Avinash

Comment: This "gimme teh codez" kind of question is going to be received poorly by the Stack Overflow audience. How about doing some research yourself and [asking again](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) when you have some code to show and an actual programming question to ask?

Comment: Use `interp1`: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html.  If you want to see where the line "extends", use the extrapolation flag `extrap`: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html

Answer (score -1):

You should narrow down your problem a bit, but I'll suggest creating a C point in the same line as A and B, and as far from A as you wish (say, k times the distance between A and B); then plot the line between C and B.

```
xC=xA+k*(xA-xB);
yC=yA+k*(yA-yB);
```

As for finding the intersection (if it is with another line), you can solve it on paper quite easily then implement it on Matlab.